# Jboss session replication : Failed to setup clustering, clustering disabled

Tags: jboss5.x, grails-2.0, mod-jk

I am trying to add clustering to my application which uses Jboss server. For replication session,
I have added `<distributable/>` tag in web.xml. But, I get following warning and session replication seems to be not working. Please suggest the best way to handle session replication for Jboss.

Warning:
`Failed to setup clustering, clustering disabled. NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/cache/pojo/jmx/PojoCacheJmxWrapperMBean`

Server : Jboss 5.1
Load balance implemented by mod_jk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you are not using a JBoss profile that has clustering related services? I believe the "default" profile does not have the clustering capabilities. You have to use the "all" profile to have the clustering capabilities.

```
JBoss_HOME
   |
   |---> bin
   |---> client
   |...
   |---> server
   |  |---> default   (clustering not enabled)
   |  |---> all  <== (clustering enabled)
   |...
```